# Visiting Andorra from Barcelona

Tags: visas, schengen, egyptian-citizens, andorra

Can I  go to Andorra for few days while visiting Barcelona with a multi entry tourist Schengen visa issued from the embassy of Spain in Egypt? Or do I need a letter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra%E2%80%93European_Union_relations#Schengen):

> Andorra has stayed outside the Schengen Agreement and maintains border controls with the EU. However as travellers to Andorra have to pass through the Schengen Area, and **Andorra does not issue any visas, but accepts Schengen visas**, Andorra is in practice a virtual part of the area. Third country nationals wishing to visit Andorra need a multi-entry Schengen visa, since to leave Andorra they must enter the Schengen area a second time.

So in short, yes, your multi-entry Schengen visa should be sufficient to enter Andorra and then to leave Andorra, re-entering the Schengen area.

Comment: The Wikipedia quote contradicts itself.  If you need a multi-entry visa to get back out of Andorra, then Andorra is NOT a "virtual part of the area."  In practice, your time in Andorra will be treated as being in Schengen, even though it legally isn't.  The reason is that you will have no proof that you entered and stayed unless you put a lot of effort into obtaining such proof.